# ODE with time-dependent frequency

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, approximation, perturbation-theory

Let's have equation
$$
\tag 1 \frac{d^{2}y(t)}{dt^{2}} +\omega^{2}(t)y(t) = 0, \quad t \in (t_{\text{in}}, \infty)
$$
Here 
$$
\omega^{2}(t) = A(t) - B(t)cos(2t),
$$ 
and functions $A(t), B(t)$ have following properties:

1) $A(t_{\text{in}}) - B(t_{\text{in}}) < 0$;

2) they are monotonically decreased with time, $\left| \frac{dB}{dt}\right| < B$, $\left|\frac{dA}{dt}\right| < A$;

3) $B(t)$ decreases faster than $A(t)$.

So there is following situation. At initial moments of time $\omega^{2}$ is alternating function, but after moment $t_{\text{final}}$, at which $A(t_{\text{final}}) - B(t_{\text{final}}) = 0$, $\omega^{2}(t)$ becomes positive only. Up to the moment $t_{\text{final}}$ $\omega^{2}$ behaves mostly as nonadiabatic function:
$$
\left|\frac{d\omega^{2} (t)}{dt}\right| \approx 2B(t)sin(2t) > -\omega^{2} (t)
$$

The question: how to construct approximate solution of Eq. $(1)$ on period $(t_{\text{in}}; t_{\text{final}})$?

Update. Specifically, I look for unstable solutions of Eq. $(1)$. In some approximation $A, B$ due to their properties, can be treated to be constants. Thus for period (t_{\text{in}}; t_{\text{final}}) Eq. $(1)$ is just Mathieu equation with $A < B, B >> 1$. But I haven't found the analysis for it.

Comment: Use perturbation theory

Comment: @MrYouMath : could you give some details how to start, if you please?

Comment: i think this class equations are called mattieu's equation.

Comment: @Abel : yes, and I look for unstable solutions. But unfortunately I've dealed with case which isn't studied exactly in literature (at least I haven't found useful references). In general, for Mathieu equation there is well-studied case $B << 1, A \geqslant B$ and worse studied case $B >> 1, A \geqslant B$. Howewer, I haven't found analysis for constant parameters $A, B$ such that $A < B$, which is exactly my case (up to the adiabaticity of $A, B$).

Answer (score 1):

This is just a sketch, you need to work out the details.

First assume $y(t)=e^{s(t)}$, where $s'' << (s')^2$. Now plug this into your ODE to get.

$$s''+(s')^2=-\omega^2$$

Now as $s'' << (s')^2$ we neglect $s''$. We get

$$(s')^2 \approx -\omega^2$$

This is "easy" to integrate. After you have found $s(x)$ proceed assuming 
$$y(t)=e^{s(t)+c(t)}$$ 
Now we assume that $c(t) << s(t)$ and $c''<(c')^2$. Now plug this into the ODE and neglect what is negligible. Then find $c(t)$, ... then assume $$y(t)=e^{s(t)+c(t)+d(t)}$$ and proceed the same manner. You will get something like a power series whicht might be divergent. This can be handled using Padé series approach.

Comment: Thank you! Just one stupid question, before I'll try to use your advise: may I somehow average over half-period of $cos(2 t)$ term, and get two equations:
$$
y'' + (A(t) - B(t))y = 0
$$
for positive part of period, and
$$
y'' + (A(t) + B(t))y = 0
$$
for negative part of period, then to construct the solutions for each half-period, and then to "sew" them together?

Comment: Is your problem form a problem set? Or is this research/application? If this is a problem set i think there might be an easier answer.

Comment: @MrYourMath : this is the part of research.

Comment: To be quiet honest, I would rather use taylor expansions of $A(t), B(t)$ and $cos(2t)$ and then solve the approximate ODEs which might be easier to solve.

Comment: @MrYourMath : specifically I look like unstable solutions for large times $t$. Thus it seems that I can't break Taylor expansion of cosine term ($A\sim \frac{1}{t}, B \sim \frac{1}{t^{\frac{5}{4}}}$)... [:(]. Maybe some nonperturbative method is needed.

Comment: I think then perturbation theory might be the right way.